# How to Shopping Cart return information using InfusionSoft and PHP

Tags: php, api, infusionsoft

I use the Infusionsoft API in PHP.
I built a website and use Infusionsoft to create copies all informations of users on that website.
On that website I have some features that users need to buy.
I made a product on Infusionsoft and users of my site have link to Shopping Cart.

Here is the problem:
How to Infusionsoft return information TRUE or FALSE a particular member of my site has made a payment.
This information must make a trigger for my website to make changes to the database and allow the user advanced options.

Trigger I know how to do, it is not a problem but do not know how to set up API to give me information from the purchase for that particular user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the Invoice table to get this information:

http://help.infusionsoft.com/developers/tables/invoice

Use this method to make the query:

http://help.infusionsoft.com/api-docs/dataservice#query

Example:

```
$returnFields = array('Id','FirstName', 'PayStatus');
$query = array('ContactId' => '5');
$contacts = $app->dsQuery("Invoice",10,0,$query,$returnFields);
```

Answer (score -1):

Of course you can search by email id in infusionsoft, they've a ready function named "findbymail", find below a link

http://help.infusionsoft.com/api-docs/contactservice#findByEmail